# About not displaying the change after editing the * .php file

Tags: php, magento, heroku

## About not displaying the change after editing the * .php file

I have the following application in heroku

https://heroku-magento-mozg.herokuapp.com/

Which has the following origin

https://github.com/mozgbrasil/heroku-magento

Using the following tool

https://heroku-magento-mozg.herokuapp.com/backdoor.php

I executed the commands to download and extract the following tool

https://github.com/kalcaddle/KodExplorer#install

Then using the following tool

http://heroku-magento-mozg.herokuapp.com/KodExplorer-master/index.php?editor

I edited the following file

https://heroku-magento-mozg.herokuapp.com/phpinfo.php

And I added script to display the value "214058"

After some time I tried to change to "21550"

But this change was not displayed

Today 15/02 in the access to phpinfo.php does not display any of the values ​​but the original file

I have seen that this occurs according to the documentation

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

My application uses Composer that downloads Magento and its dependencies

It turns out that in the installation step when reporting the database data is being returned error, then I would try to edit the Magento file as per the instructions

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84782/database-connection-error-magento-installation

As my application repository does not have the Magento files since Composer is used how would I make this possible editing?

Answer (score 0):

If you've changed the value using `heroku cli`, this won't work, because of the [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). You'll need to commit the change and push the change up, and deploy the new changes.

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the
>   most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running
>   processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no
>   files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and
>   any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or
>   restarted

Assuming you're using `git` to manage your code, just redeploy them. `Heroku` will pick these changes up and deploy a new version of your app.